# Arduino MEGA2560 wake up using DS3231 RTC

Tags: arduino-mega

I am trying to set the Arduino MEGA 2560 R3 into sleep mode and wake it up with an RTC DS3231 via interrupt. I was following this tutorial:
[Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Sleep-and-Wakeup-Test-With-DS3231-RTC/)

One of the libraries included is the "LowPower" library, you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power/). It produces the following error while compiling:

```
C:\XX\Arduino\libraries\Low-Power-master\LowPower.cpp: In member function 'void LowPowerClass::idle(period_t, adc_t, timer5_t, timer4_t, timer3_t, timer2_t, timer1_t, timer0_t, spi_t, usart3_t, usart2_t, usart1_t, usart0_t, twi_t)':

C:\XX\Arduino\libraries\Low-Power-master\LowPower.cpp:562:49: error: 'power_usart3_disable' was not declared in this scope

  if (usart3 == USART3_OFF) power_usart3_disable();

                                                 ^

C:\XX\Arduino\libraries\Low-Power-master\LowPower.cpp:597:48: error: 'power_usart3_enable' was not declared in this scope

  if (usart3 == USART3_OFF) power_usart3_enable();

                                                ^

exit status 1
Error while compiling for Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

I dont understand why there should be any functions in the library, which are not declared...This would mean noone could use it?! I am not an expert in C++ so maybe one of you could tell me what the issue could be. I am glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

after further web research, it looks like this is a bug which hasnt been fixed yet.
it was discussed previously [here](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power/issues/30) and [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/5286).

My solution was to go into the "LowPower.cpp" scroll down to the lines, where the functions are not declared and I just out-commented them. Compiling works now.